# Отображение контента по кнопка jquery

Tags: jquery

Приветствую.
Сверстал страницу на bootstrap'e. Расположил с одной стороны 4 кнопки, с другой стороны место под контент. 
Задача: по нажатию на каждую из кнопок выводить тот или иной контент без обновления страницы + при отображении нового контента, скрывать тот, которые уже был открыт ранее. 
Копался в интернете, подобного решения найти не смог. Может у кого-нибудь завалялось готовое решение?

Comment: Вы описали работу обычных табов - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со старта в голову приходит что то вроде этого:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button_id').on('click', function(){
    $('#container_id').slideUp(500).html('content').slideDown(500);
  });
});
```

Или используйте [табы](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) в бутстрапе, как готовое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Чем не подходит решение со стилевым свойством display:none?Назначьте классы для тех блоков, что нужно скрывать с display: none и потом просто используйте либо addclass() либо removeclass().